# Get IntelliLink R 4.0 version info (Opel Astra K)

Tags: opel, astra, infotainment

I have a very annoying volume bug with this infotainment system¹ and that is why I would like to get the version info of mine and see if there is an update. So far no *about* button gives me the software version of my *IntelliLink R 4.0*

¹: Radio and Spotify off. the Google Maps navigation lady speaks and right after the radio comes back -despite it was off- with full volume! There is also a very much volume difference between radio and anything that runs on Android Auto (Maps, Spotify, WhatsApp notifications etc.)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD5SQuXx5zQ) with the passcode 20130822 opens up the developer mode and within there one can check the IntelliLink R 4.0 version.
(At least works for my headunit)

Answer (score 1):

The Astra K was released in 2015 so it would still be under warranty (as of 12/2017)

I'd take it to a local dealership and explain the problem as it could be a faulty radio or a software upgrade could be required